# Transforming images and mp3 files into a video file on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp4, avi

I am thinking to start the development of a new project and I have some ideas in mind, but I am not sure how much is doable in android.
The steps of the app would be:

1. The user selects a set of images from Gallery
2. The user selects an audio file from external storage
3. I combine the images and the sound (each image is displayed for a timeframe) into a movie file that can be exported to YouTube

From my research I wasn't able to find any way to create the movie. All the answers contained links to android NDK and external codecs.

So my question is: which would be the easiest way of making this on android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, your idea is feasible. You need to have Ffmpeg compiled for android. First have a look for it at [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20991431/3098658).Then decide yourselves as per need.

After you have Ffmpeg compiled for android, you can just search and `extract/add audio` as per your needs. To give a a start have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679274/ffmpeg-command-to-combine-audio-and-images) and [FFmpeg Docs Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)/[Official Example](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide&ei=2B3xUoDMFYL_rAeGnoDIDg&usg=AFQjCNF0jT-ix902Q_twI0PC1L9qe6nb3w&sig2=rCWZ-pr4WRw-00avkZUUwg&bvm=bv.60444564,d.bmk&cad=rja).

To make `video from images` have a look at [Ffmpeg official example](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%2520a%2520video%2520slideshow%2520from%2520images&ei=Ih7xUp6ZBse3rAe1pYDACA&usg=AFQjCNGNxCNh8C6u8hxFRTho_5MIHm3vHg&sig2=0NNGyDSLipKk-7_5ULZYqQ&cad=rja). You can find plenty of these on google.

After having all these things on your hand, you are ready for your project. I would suggest to try and familiarize yourself for `Ffmpeg` on Windows/Linux as per your need first.

Hope this would help.

Cheers.:)

Comment: Thanks @Jay for your detailed answer. So just to get thing straight, there are no real android api that allow this

Comment: @Alin no there is no direct API in android

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it in the next days and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: I am getting lost. In one of your links there was a pretty cool implementation ffmpeg4android but that requires licensing. I think that somehow I can manage to compile the sources with androud ndk and copy them to jdi folder, but from there I have no idea how to continue. Any hints ?